# setof-like with duplicates in prolog?

Tags: prolog

As you know `setof/3` can order a list with duplicate removal. Is there a way to use `setof/3` keeping duplicates? Basically is there a built-in sorting function setof-like? (meaning if I have `[a,3,2,c,b]` then I'll get `[2,3,a,b,c]`.

PS: don't suggest "*Implement a merge sort/insertion sort/whatever*". I'm looking for a built-in way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/aggregate.html%27%29%29), note the Distinguish argument.